# Cloudinary upload works locally but error on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, cloudinary

I'm getting the error `(node:22) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path'  of undefined` when trying to upload an image to Cloudinary on my Heroku deployment, when I do it locally it works just fine.

Where the error occurs:

```
const upload = require("../utils/multer");
const cloudinary = require("../utils/cloudinary");

//Add Question Set
router.post("/add", upload.single("questionSetImage"), async (req, res) => {
    //Get the Author Email
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    let user = await User.findById(decoded._id);

    //Validate Data
    const { error } = questionSetValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).json(error.details[0].message);

    console.log(req.file.path); //error occured here
    const imageUpload = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
    console.log(imageUpload);

    //Create New Question
    const questionSet = await new QuestionSet({
        questionSet: req.body.questionSet,
        theme: req.body.theme,
        visible: req.body.visible,
        totalQuestion: req.body.totalQuestion,
        author: user._id,
        questionSetImage: imageUpload.secure_url,
        cloudinaryID: imageUpload.public_id,
    });
    try {
        const saveQuestionSet = await questionSet.save();
        res.status(200).json(saveQuestionSet);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
});
```

My Multer Code:

```
const path = require("path");

//Multer config
module.exports = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({}),
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        if (ext !== ".jpg" && ext !== ".jpeg" && ext !== ".png") {
            cb(new Error("File type is not supported!"), false);
            return;
        }
        cb(null, true);
    },
});
```

My Cloudinary Code:

```
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
require("dotenv").config();

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

module.exports = cloudinary;
```

I have no idea why it's not working only for the Heroku deployment. It says that the error has something to do with the path, however locally the path works fine. I don't know if the file is getting uploaded properly or not.

EDIT: Turns out it doesn't even work locally. I get the same error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

Comment: It looks like `req.file` is undefined. How are you making your request to `/add`?

Comment: In my postman form-data I added a file for questionSetImage: https://imgur.com/a/Q6AK8Ii. When i try to console.log(req.file) it does say undefined

Comment: I got it to work locally after realizing that some of my validations were incorrect. I tried to upload the same image (454kb) to Heroku and then got the same undefined error. Then I tried uploading a smaller size image (75kb) and it somehow worked. Tried again with original image and now it also works.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you are able to clearly explain what the problem was and how you fixed it, feel free to add a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) below. If you choose to do that, please read [answer], as the goal is to provide useful information for other users in the future. Alternatively, if you're not sure what the issue was, but you no longer need answers, you may choose to delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work locally after realizing that some of my validations were incorrect. I tried to upload the same image (454kb) to Heroku and then got the same undefined error. Then I tried uploading a smaller size image (75kb) and it somehow worked. Tried again with original image and now it also works